# "Sender" is to "receiver" as "distributor" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, analogy

I'm looking for a word that means the party being distributed to by a distributor.

I'm in the film industry. There are wholesalers *and* distributors. Even though both roles could be called wholesaling, functionally, they are never talked about that way within the industry.

The recipients of a distributed film are only referred to by category. For example, 'cinemas', 'retailers', 'churches'. I am looking for a hypernym to all those categories.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Probably not the word you are looking for so I'll just make a comment, but in my mind the opposite of 'to send' is 'to receive' and the opposite of 'to distribute' is 'to collect'.  So 'collector' might fit.

Comment: @Jim That's got my mind going in a new direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED defines ***distributee*** as “A person to whom a share falls in the distribution of the estate of an intestate.”  That may not be what you are looking for.

Typically distributors are ***wholesalers*** who distribute to ***retailers***.  Looking up synonyms for those might be more profitable in this instance.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid *distributee* but I hadn't thought of the *retailers* and synonyms.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Wholesaler to retailers is certainly the ordinary model, but in many very large industries the distributor is not a wholesaler who buys and sells on his account but a provider of distribution services to co-ops or centrally-owned or -franchised retailers. . .  but *distributee* is certainly too ugly to contemplate.

Comment: @StoneyB that's exactly my problem.  I'm in the film industry.  There are wholesalers AND distributors.  Even though both roles could be called wholesaling, functionally, they are never talked about that way within the industry.  The recipients of a distributed film are only referred to by category.  For example, 'cinemas', 'retailers', 'churches'.  I am looking for the perfect word do describe all those categories.  I love the English language!

Comment: I don't think you'll find single word which embraces all relevant categories **and none of the irrelevant ones**.

Comment: @StoneyB You might be right. :(

Comment: Another term occurs to me: **outlet**

Answer (score 3):

If you're speaking of a person who receives goods from either a sender or a distributor—or a seller, a manufacturer, or anybody else—the normal term is *recipient*.

Since the advent of electronic communications, *receiver* has tended to be confined to the apparatus receiving an electronic signal; from this use evolved the very odd construction *She spoke into the receiver*. For much of the 20th century a "receiver" with no qualifying context would have been understood as a radio set. It will be interesting to see whether the trend is reversed now that most consumers receive signals through computers and mobile phones, neither of which I've ever seen called a "receiver".

Comment: That is very interesting.  I was tempted by *receiver* but it just doesn't feel right in this context (same with *distributee*).  They both work in a fundamental sense, but lack the X factor.

Comment: @MFB: Define “X factor”; you mean sex appeal, right?

Comment: @tchrist Well that's probably putting it a little strongly.  Its not being used in marketing so it doesn't need sex-appeal.  I mean not clumsy-sounding, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In the film industry, at least in some geographies, the end-user, after the distributor, is the 'exhibitor'.

This agrees with the class of businesses you call 'cinemas', along with private screening entities such as educational/ religious/ cultural, etc.

I am not very sure how far 'exhibitor' as a trade term is current in different geographies/ markets.

Comment: Or perhaps, screeners? This might be interpreted as someone who filters for content, but in the industry, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

As well as synonyms for *retailers* you could also research synonyms for *cinemas*, since you are looking for the "end-users" of the film.

***Playhouses*** might be suitable, for example, although you may need to contextualise it by introducing the term with "cinemas and other playhouses". I'm a bit surprised the industry doesn't have a generic term.

Comment: Some more good ideas, thank you!  The industry may have a generic term, but know one I know can put their finger on it.  Funny thing about English is that we use terms as generic as "they", "them", "those guys" a lot more than we realise.. Even funnier is that we all know what each other is talking about!  Its all about context, and some words just don't have enough context of their own.

Comment: This was my initial thought as well. What about re-distributors? Less ugly that distributees.